# Can't install Ubuntu alongside Windows XP with a USB

Tags: boot

i have Ubuntu in my USB, so i plug in my Dell Dimension 3000 (Windows XP SP3, 500MB RAM, Hard Disk 60GB) and boot from the USB so i take a look at Ubuntu and then i started the Setup from Ubuntu but there was no option of "Install Alongside Windows" it was only the option to create a partition but i want to Install Ubuntu alongside Windows

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using Wubi, you will need to create a separate partition for Ubuntu. "Install alongside", as used by the installer, means shrinking the Windows partition and creating a new one for Ubuntu in the freed space. You can then boot into either operating system.

A few miscellaneous points:

- I believe Wubi is no longer supported;
- You may find 500Mb RAM a little tight for modern Ubuntu versions - you should check the mimimum and recommended memory amounts for the version you are installing;
- I understand that security updates for XP will cease in a few months, so you may decide it's not worth keeping that XP partition anyway.